# SELECT the current value of a column based on date of another table

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I have 4 tables:

- INVOICE, contains the entry date.
- INVOICE_ITEM contains the product cod's.
- PRODUCTS, here contains the STANDARD column, It shows only the current standard value.
- PRODUCT_HIST (contains the standard value changes of the products table).

I'm trying to select the "standard" value (Can be 'Y' or 'N') of the product_hist based on the invoice entry date.

My select below isn't showing the correct values

```
SELECT NT.INVOICE
      , NT.PROVIDER
      , NT.ENTRY
      , NTI.PRODUCT
      , P.COD
      , P.NAME
      , Nvl(P.STANDARD, 'Y') "STANDARD_ACTUAL"
      , COALESCE ((SELECT To_Char(MAX(PH.DATE)) FROM PRODUCT_HIST PH
     WHERE PH.COD = P.COD),
                  P.STANDARD, 'S') "STANDARD2"
      FROM INVOICE NT
      INNER JOIN INVOICE_ITEM NTI ON NT.NOTE = NTI.NOTE AND NT.PROVIDER = NTI.PROVIDER
      INNER JOIN PRODUCTS P ON P.COD = NTI.PRODUCT
     WHERE NT.ENTRY BETWEEN TO_DATE('01/01/2019','DD/MM/YYYY') AND TO_DATE('31/12/2019','DD/MM/YYYY')+0.99999
```

I wanna show the current value when the invoice had an entry (STANDARD2)

In the COALESCE column I have the last value, it's not based on the invoice entry

I'm 3 days on it and cant make it work. Would be grateful if someone can help me, please.

Comment: please take a look at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query the date is based on product_history how can it be related to invoice?

Comment: Product_history Inner join through Invoice_item that Inner join Invoice (That contains Entry Date)

Comment: i don't know your data, but somehow it seems like a misconception, take a look ant ivoice date, that can be raltzed to history table but maybe an update occured..  so provide a [mre]

Comment: Sharing data sample may help us to help you out. However, based on understanding developed, you need to make union of PRODUCTS and PRODUCT_HIST tables as the history table may not cover the given date range in where cluase.